# Monorepos and cross package development. To use src/ or dist/?

Tags: typescript, webpack, yarnpkg, theory, monorepo

My fellow yarn workspace typescript monorepo-nians,

**Question:** When you are working within a monorepo are you able to import and use source code across packages or do you rely on the build steps artifact to use a package from a separate package?

For example you have this folder structure

```
packages/
  frontend/
  api/
  dateTimeHelpers/
    src/
    dist/
```

Both `frontend/` and `api/` have a dependency on the `dateTimeHelpers` package

```
frontend/ + api/ package.json

dependencies: {
  dateTimeHelpers: "1.0.0"
}
```

You are running `frontend` , hot reloading and the like and want to add a function to the `dateTimeHelpers` package and use said function within the `frontend` package

Do you have to *compile* the `dateTimeHelpers` package (aka `frontend` is using the *dateTimeHelpers/dist* folder), or will your frontend import the *src* code from `dateTimeHelpers` and compile it on the fly (or just when it builds)?

All the packages are written in TypeScript and require a build step in order to be used.

Thank you for entertaining this.  I am having a hard time seeing what I should be shooting for.  I have `dist` usage working - but I would like to not be running two build commands or have to build ad-hoc when developing.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I am going to close this question, because I believe that this is the proper behavior to fix it!

Seems that even within the TS community, there is confusion on this.

When you build within `frontend/` it should know that `dateTimeHelpers` is a dependency and subsequently build that.

So this means that each package is always working out of `dist/` but webpack knows to compile across packages.

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/releases/tag/v8.0.0

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/1114